# How can I simplify these CSS selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have some code that I think may be bulky and could be simplified. I haven't found anything that helps in my situation. I am trying to make it so that when I hover over a `div`, an `h2` and `p` get underlined. It works fine like this:

```
.test:hover h2, .test:hover p {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

But I was wondering if I could simplify it in some way, not having to repeat `.test:hover` twice.

Comment: One option would be to leverage a CSS preprocessor like [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/) or [Less](https://lesscss.org/), both of which support nesting which can make for DRY-er, more expressive style source code.  This may be overkill in your case, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to support Internet Explorer this can be accomplished with the [`:is` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is):

```css
.test:hover :is(h2, p) {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <h1>An H1</h1>
  <h2>An H2</h2>
  <p>A paragraph</p>
</div>
```

An alternative would be to leverage a CSS preprocessor like Sass or Less, both of which support nesting which can make for DRY-er, more expressive style source code. This may be overkill in your case, though.  Here's an example in Sass' `SCSS` format:

```
.test:hover {
  h2, p {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a new pseudo-class [`:is`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is) which will allow this..

> The `:is()` CSS pseudo-class function takes a selector list as its argument, and selects any element that can be selected by one of the selectors in that list.

```css
.test:hover :is(h2, p) {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
</div>

<div class="test">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use it:

```html
:is(h1, p) .test:hover { 
  text-decoration: underline; 
}
```